# jVi alternative that supports .vimrc

Tags: vim, netbeans, ide

Considering that [jVi does not support .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404875/jvi-in-netbeans) files, what alternatives do we have that do support .vimrc files? Specifically, I have many handy insert-mode mappings that I would prefer not to give up, such as this:

```
inoremap kk <Esc>A
```

Additionally, there are some mappings that I could live without, but I think that I will need real VIM for, such as this:

```
inoremap hh <c-o>?\%<c-r>=line('.')<Return>l\({}\\|\[]\\|<>\\|><\\|()\\|""\\|''\\|><lt>\)?s+1<Return>
```

**Note:** I know that the question of VIM keybindings in Netbeans / Eclipse / [any IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294613/does-any-ide-have-a-vi-keybindings-options) comes up often enough, but in this question I am not asking about VIM keybindings, but rather about .vimrc specifically, or better yet *real VIM* embedded in Netbeans. I have not seen this facet addressed in any other of the myriad of ostensibly-similar posts.

I have looked at [Vi Vim for netbeans / ViEx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/viex/), [vim for netbeans](http://www.ohloh.net/p/viex), and others. Apparently VIM includes [a socket interface for integration into an IDE](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/netbeans.html) which is interestingly enough called "netbeans". The help file for this feature lists a few projects, but is terribly out of date. The only project that still seems active from that file is [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk) but their website is down.

Comment: It looks like you've nailed the question. What language do you use? What features do you need in netbeans? Did you consider using Eclipse instead of Netbeans? Eclim works quite well.

Comment: I find Eclipse to be unacceptably slow, even with 4 GiB of RAM and a modern dual-core processor. Additionally, Eclipse has terrible support for remote file systems (FTP or SSH). Other than that, I do like Eclipse and have used it much more than Netbeans. For remote coding I'm almost exclusively in PHP / MySQL / HTML / Javascript. For local coding I'll do anything including PHP, Python, Java, and maybe some Mono / C#. My OS is Kubuntu Linux.

Comment: jVi has an option panel where you can add your own mappings. Here, your `kk` works as is but your `hh` doesn't. With some effort, you might be able to "port" most of your custom mappings.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the socket interface. I didn't know about that. And also the `hh` mapping :)

Comment: Thanks, Romainl, putting things in that configuration textarea helps.

Comment: While any good IDE supports customised key mappings, they don't solve the problem that any Vim emulator is just an emulator, and awkward for experienced Vim power-users. I agree with @romainl that Eclim works quite well, but I haven't found an equivalent for JetBrains-based IDEs yet, and I'm getting really tired of people saying 'just use IdeaVim'. Despite many years of good work going into IdeaVim, it's still a clunky, poor substitute for vim.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has nice Vim plugin, and it supports vimrc. Ofc it's not 100% compatible but like 85-90% which is greater. IDE itself is not free but you can use  development version which is pretty stable https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

The other nice solution as @romainl mention is Eclim http://eclim.org/
It gives you IDE power in your Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Is [gVim](http://www.vim.org/) sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I am currently using VIM, but was hoping to get into an IDE. gVIM and VIM it will be until I can find an IDE that supports a real VIM experience.

Comment: @dotancohen Only Vim provides a real Vim experience.

Comment: Indeed, which is why it's disappointing that there doesn't seem to be a NetBeans-style socket interface for JetBrains, PyCharm, Idea, etc. I think I'm going to have to change IDEs.