# What is this Vim wizardry?

Tags: vim

In a question about [jVi](https://superuser.com/questions/464369/jvi-alternative-that-supports-vimrc) and its capability to parse .vimrc, the author gives an example of a complex vim binding that he asserts jVi would not be able to handle:

```
inoremap hh <c-o>?\%<c-r>=line('.')<Return>l\({}\\|\[]\\|<>\\|><\\|()\\|""\\|''\\|><lt>\)?s+1<Return>
```

I wonder what (mostly how) it does. So far I get:

- <c-o> : execute one command in normal mode and return to insert mode
- ?/%n : look backwards for a character with the specified dec / hex code

  - what is the point of inserting the line number here?
- the last part looks for a specific combination of brackets and places the cursor there

  - I don't understand how `l` can be used like that

Care to clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is as you indicated.  And the first `?` does 
start a backwards search.

A pattern sequence like `\%15l` restricts the search to line 15, the `l` after 
the first `<Return>` is the end of such a sequence.  The mapping uses 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the special `=` register (`:help i_CTRL-R`), and 
the expression `line('.')` to insert the current line number into that 
sequence, preventing the search from going to a different line.

The rest of the mapping up to the final `?` character is a fairly straight 
forward regular expression to match any of a number of character sequences.

The final `?` indicates the end of the pattern, the `s+1` portion causes the 
cursor to be positioned 1 character after the start of the match (`:help 
search-offset`).

Comment: I appreciate the :help references.